# How do you install Drupal with command line only?

Tags: command-line, installation, drupal

All the Drupal documentation I can find has a step of "going to a browser and continuing installation there".

How can I perform these steps from my command line?

I am trying to have a site where I can fire up an AWS instance and install Drupal etc by command line.

Comment: I don't what "an AWS instance" is, but you're aware that you can (should) browse to the *public* URL of the website-to-be? (Like *anyone* who goes to that URL will be able to continue the installation.)

Comment: Amazon Web Services.

Comment: Hmmm, I figured it couldn't be that... Then I just don't understand the question. :-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is browser installation not an option? Drupal is a web framework so presumably you will need to have web access to it at some point. Why not do the standard installation with the browser?

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [Drush's provision script](http://drupal.org/project/drush).

> Drush is a command line shell and scripting interface for Drupal, a veritable Swiss Army knife designed to make life easier for those of us who spend some of our working hours hacking away at the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little pain to install drupal from curl due to all the different redirects the install script makes. You also need to read and write cookies at exact moments. However: I have made a curl script which will install drupal from the command line :)  Note: Only tested with drupal-6.x, php5 and the php curl extension.

> As a site note before doing this, you should really consider using the
>   drush site-install command!
>
> This was tested on drupal-6.20 with PHP 5.3. Druapl 7 needs to have
>   Javascript enabled as far as I can see. And therefor will not install
>   from curl! You should also note that correct files for settings.php
>   and the file folder needs to be set in order to make this work
>   (otherwise we will get errors and curl will not compleate!)
>
> First we add a curl class.
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> // class found on php.net
> // http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php
>
> class mycurl {
>      protected $_useragent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1';
>      protected $_url;
>      protected $_followlocation;
>      protected $_timeout;
>      protected $_maxRedirects;
>      protected $_cookieFileLocation = './cookie.txt';
>      protected $_post;
>      protected $_postFields;
>      protected $_referer ="http://www.google.com";
>
>      protected $_session;
>      protected $_webpage;
>      protected $_includeHeader;
>      protected $_noBody;
>      protected $_status;
>      protected $_binaryTransfer;
>      public    $authentication = 0;
>      public    $auth_name      = '';
>      public    $auth_pass      = '';
>
>      public function useAuth($use){
>        $this->authentication = 0;
>        if($use == true) $this->authentication = 1;
>      }
>
>      public function setName($name){
>        $this->auth_name = $name;
>      }
>      public function setPass($pass){
>        $this->auth_pass = $pass;
>      }
>
>      public function __construct($url,$followlocation = true,$timeOut = 30,$maxRedirecs = 4,$binaryTransfer = false,$includeHeader = true,$noBody = false)
>      {
>          $this->_url = $url;
>          $this->_followlocation = $followlocation;
>          $this->_timeout = $timeOut;
>          $this->_maxRedirects = $maxRedirecs;
>          $this->_noBody = $noBody;
>          $this->_includeHeader = $includeHeader;
>          $this->_binaryTransfer = $binaryTransfer;
>
>          $this->_cookieFileLocation = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt';
>
>      }
>
>      public function setReferer($referer){
>        $this->_referer = $referer;
>      }
>
>      public function setCookiFileLocation($path)
>      {
>          $this->_cookieFileLocation = $path;
>      }
>
>      public function setPost ($postFields)
>      {
>         $this->_post = true;
>         $this->_postFields = $postFields;
>      }
>
>      public function setUserAgent($userAgent)
>      {
>          $this->_useragent = $userAgent;
>      }
>
>      public function createCurl($url = 'nul')
>      {
>         if($url != 'nul'){
>           $this->_url = $url;
>         }
>
>          $s = curl_init();
>
>          curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_URL,$this->_url);
>          curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Expect:'));
>          curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,$this->_timeout);
>          curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,$this->_maxRedirects);
>          curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
>          curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,$this->_followlocation);
>          curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$this->_cookieFileLocation);
>          curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$this->_cookieFileLocation);
>
>          if($this->authentication == 1){
>            curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->auth_name.':'.$this->auth_pass);
>          }
>          if($this->_post)
>          {
>              curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POST,true);
>              curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$this->_postFields);
>
>          }
>
>          if($this->_includeHeader)
>          {
>                curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
>          }
>
>          if($this->_noBody)
>          {
>              curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
>          }
>          /*
>          if($this->_binary)
>          {
>              curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);
>          }
>          */
>          curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$this->_useragent);
>          curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_REFERER,$this->_referer);
>
>          $this->_webpage = curl_exec($s);
>          $this->_status = curl_getinfo($s,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
>          curl_close($s);
>
>      }
>
>    public function getHttpStatus()
>    {
>        return $this->_status;
>    }
>
>    public function __tostring(){
>       return $this->_webpage;
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> And now we create the script with the curl class.
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> include_once "curl.inc";
>
> // your site
> $site_url = 'http://drupal';
>
> // profile
> $profile = 'default';
>
> // locale
> $locale = 'en';
>
> // database
> $db_path = 'drupal';
>
> // database user
> $db_user = 'root';
>
> // database pass
> $db_pass = 'password';
>
> // database host
> $db_host = 'localhost';
>
> // name of site
> $site_name = 'site_name';
>
> // site email
> $site_mail = 'site_mail@site.com';
>
> // admin account name
> $account_name = 'admin';
>
> // admin account email
> $account_mail = 'admin@admin.dk';
>
> // admin account pass
> $account_pass = 'admin1234';
>
> // date time zone
> $date_default_timezone = '-39600';
>
> // use clean url.
> $clean_url = '1';
>
> // update status module
> $update_status_module = '1';
>
> // end of settings
>  // create a url for curling db settings
> $url_str = "db_path=$db_path&";
> $url_str.= "db_user=$db_user&";
> $url_str.= "db_pass=$db_pass&";
> $url_str.= "db_host=$db_host&";
> $url_str.= "db_prefix=&";
> $url_str.= "db_port=&";
> $url_str.= "op=Save and continue" . "&";
> $url_str.= "form_id=install_settings_form";
> $url_str = urlencode($url_str);
>
> $url = "$site_url/install.php?profile=$profile";
> $curl = new mycurl($url, true);
> $curl->createCurl();
> echo $curl;
>
> $url = "$site_url/install.php?profile=$profile&locale=$locale";
> $curl = new mycurl($url, true);
> $curl->setPost($url_str);
> $curl->createCurl();
> echo $curl;
>
> $url = "$site_url/install.php?profile=$profile&locale=$locale&op=do_nojs&id=1";
>
> $curl = new mycurl($url, true);
> $curl->setPost($url_str);
> $curl->createCurl();
> echo $curl;
>
> $url = "$site_url/install.php?profile=$profile&locale=$locale&op=finished&id=1";
>
> $curl = new mycurl($url, true);
> $curl->setPost($url_str);
> $curl->createCurl();
> echo $curl;
>
>
> // set settings for loading database with site base settings
> $url_str = "site_name=$site_name&";
> $url_str.= "site_mail=$site_mail&";
> $url_str.= "account[name]=$account_name&";
> $url_str.= "account[mail]=$account_mail&";
> $url_str.= "account[pass][pass1]=$account_pass&";
> $url_str.= "account[pass][pass2]=$account_pass&";
> $url_str.= "date_default_timezone=$date_default_timezone&";
> $url_str.= "clean_url=$clean_url&";
> $url_str.= "form_id=install_configure_form&";
> $url_str.= "update_status_module[1]=$update_status_module";
>
>
> $url = "$site_url/install.php?profile=default&locale=en";
> $curl = new mycurl($url, true);
> $curl->setPost($url_str);
> $curl->createCurl();
> echo $curl;
>
> die();
> ?>
> ```
>
> — [Install Drupal with cURL](http://www.os-cms.net/content/article/view/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could script out the steps of the URL using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).

Comment: How does one do that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could [use the extension called Densite](http://os-cms.net/drush_shell_scripts_for_creating_drupal_sites). This will do it for 6.x and 5.x - test only on ubuntu though.

The link to installing drupal with curl is broken.

[Installing Drupal 6 using the Command Line with Drush and Twill](http://lin-clark.com/blog/installing-drupal-6-using-command-line-drush-and-twill)

Answer (score 0):

The working Curl script can be found here: http://www.os-cms.net/content/article/view/1

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to check out drush_site_install6 drush module available here:
http://drupal.org/project/drush_site_install6

Answer (score 0):

What about using  [Lynx text browser](http://www.vordweb.co.uk/standards/download_lynx.htm)?